# running node app with exports.object from command line and lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am still in the process of learning `node` and have come across this issue. In the following situation, and using a silly example (the full code can not be placed here), when I run in the terminal `node index.js somethinghere`, the code does not execute. I realise that `event` and `context` have no bearing in this example, but they do in the code I am currently writing.

Is this because I am doing `exports.imageRs`?

How would I get it to run on the command line by passing in arguments?

Note that the original code is to be run on both `aws lambda` and from the command line.

file `index.js`

```
exports.imageRs = function (event, context) {
  console.log(process.argv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have shown Node will define `exports.imageRs` function but it won't execute it.

The fix is something along these lines:

```
exports.imageRs = function (event, context) {
  console.log(process.argv);
};

if (!module.parent) {
  exports.imageRs();
}
```

`!module.parent` check prevents the code inside from executing when your module is required from other modules, which is probably what you want.

```
$ node index.js somethinghere
[ '/path/to/node',
  '/path/to/index.js',
  'somethinghere' ]

$ node
> require('./index')
{ imageRs: [Function] }
```

Comment: Lambda still complain when I do that. I got it working with `if (!process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT) {
    exports.imageRs();
}`

Comment: @hyprstack Thanks.It worked for me. add it as an accepted answer